# Jensen's inequality for composite functions

Tags: probability, jensen-inequality

Let $f(\cdot)$ be a convex function and let $g(\cdot)$ be any function.
According to Jensen's inequality, we know
$$f[E(X)]\leq E[f(X)].$$

However, is the following true or not?
$$f[E(g(X))]\leq E[f(g(X))].$$

Note we are taking expectation with respect to $g(X)$, instead of moving the expectation into the argument of $g(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d$ and some probability space $\Omega$, and that $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. A further, key assumption is that **$g$ is measurable.** Note that a sufficient condition for measurability of $g$ is piecewise continuity (with finitely many junmps).

Then $Y\:=g(X):\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is still a random variable, as random variables are measurable functions and composition of measurable functions is measurable, and thus you can apply Jensen inequality to $Y$, yielding $f[E(g(X))]\leq E[f(g(X))]$.

If $g$ is non-measurable, you might not be able to say that $Y$ is a random variable, and defining its expected value in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But the expectation is taken with respect to $X$, i.e., we are calculating and comparing $f(E_X(Y))$ and $E_Xf(Y)$. Therefore I don't see the conclusion.

Comment: I don't understand yor doubt. Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is the probability on $\Omega$. Then $E_Y[Y]=\int Y (\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\int g(X (\omega))d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$.